# How to make qr code generator with multiple info in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, qr-code

I Have created a qr code generator with swiftui. i used uiimage to create qr code with datepicker, i want to create with multipile info with qr code generator, I want to add a integer as a picker to combine with the datepicker, what do i need to add for the function to make multiple info.

Here is my orginial code.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var start = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("", selection: $start, displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute])
                .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
            Generate(start: $start)
        }
    }
}

struct GenerateQRCode: View {
    @Binding var start: Date
        
        let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
        let cont = CIContext()
        
        var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
            let df = DateFormatter()
            df.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
            return df
        }
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Image(uiImage: imageGenerate(start))
                .interpolation(.none)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
    
    func imageGenerate(_ start: Date)-> UIImage {
        let str = dateFormatter.string(from: start)
        let data = str.data(using: .utf8)
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        if let qr = filter.outputImage {
            if let qrImage = cont.createCGImage(qr, from: qr.extent){
                return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
            }
        }
        return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function doesn't even need the `start` parameter (since you already passing the local ivar). It also doesn't need to be a `@Binding`, since you are not modifying it, but assuming other context your function could be something like: `imageGenerate(date: Date, number: Int) -> UIImage`.

Comment: @Alladinian do you have an example can show me?